# .NET vNext only uses one dll from referenced package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm adding a dependency (`mongocsharpdriver`) to the `net45` dependencies section like this:

```
    "net45": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Data": "",
            "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "",
            "mongocsharpdriver": "1.9.1"
        }
    },
```

Based on all other dependencies I've used, this should be enough to make it work. Here's some sample code I threw in to test it:

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray test;
MongoDB.Driver.RemoveFlags test2;
```

With this in place, I'd expect that to compile, but `MongoDB.Driver` isn't recognized. `MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray` works fine.

Is having two assemblies in the same package an unsupported scenario in vNext, or is it not implemented yet?

Comment: As is pointed out below it isn't supported by the kre that is part of the ctp but has been fixed and works in a kre that doesn't work with the ctp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was just a bug in ASP.NET vNext and has been fixed in more recent nightly builds, which are available on the ASP.NET vNext MyGet feed.

Here's the bug: https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/266

Comment: I just installed VS14 CTP2 and it appears that build has been included and things are working again. Thanks!